# What is wrong with my java selection sort algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, selection, selection-sort

Update: I've swapped the swap method for the Collection.swap method and everything works now. Thanks for the help.

I have a selection sort algorithm that aims to sort basketball players based on their age. programPlayerList is an unsorted Array List of basketball players that have been taken from a CSV that has been web scraped. programSortedPlayerList is an Array List that is to hold the players based on their sorted age. swap is a method that swaps the player objects. However, when I run the code, the players have not been sorted correctly. What is wrong with my code?

```
public static ArrayList<Player> sortByAge() {   
    for(int i = 0; i < programPlayerList.size(); i++) {
        programSortedPlayerList.add(programPlayerList.get(i));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < programSortedPlayerList.size()-1; i++) {
        int indexofmin = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < programSortedPlayerList.size(); j++) {
            if(programSortedPlayerList.get(j).getAge() < programSortedPlayerList.get(indexofmin).getAge()) {
                indexofmin = j;
            }
        }
        swap(programSortedPlayerList.get(i), programSortedPlayerList.get(indexofmin));
    }
    return programSortedPlayerList;
 }
```

[Swap Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqXP8.png)
[Printing age](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGLAJ.png)
[Algorithm output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14YAn.png)

Comment: Where are you printing? And how? Also, `swap` looks **wrong** (since you pass it references).

Comment: *"swap is a method that swaps the player objects"* - include the code for this method, too. *"the players have not been sorted correctly"* - include the input, actual result and expected result. See [mcve].

Comment: I've made the changes. Any more needed?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Including your code directly in your questions (instead of linking to screenshots of it) will make reading it easier for potential answerers.

Comment: Ok, duly noted.

Comment: You may have duly noted, but 7 hours later you still have screenshots of code, instead of code as text.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Your calls of `swap` are not going to change anything to `programSortedPlayerList`.

The arguments passed to `swap` are not modified by it. As soon as you assign a new object to either argument variable, you only have a local effect. The calling code will not see any change to the passed objects. This is the principle of "call by value": the objects (references) are passed to `swap`, but whatever `swap` does, it cannot change the references of the caller.

In order to change the order of elements in `programSortedPlayerList` you'll have to call `programSortedPlayerList.set` at some point.

So for example:

```
public static void swap(ArrayList<Player> playerList, int i, int j) {
    Player temp = playerList.get(i);
    playerList.set(i, list.get(j));
    playerList.set(j, temp);
}
```

...and call as:

```
swap(programSortedPlayerList, i, indexofmin);
```